# Multisites with subdirs for each site

Tags: 7, multi-sites

I'm starting with Drupal and I would like to have one instance of Drupal on my dev plateform with each project in a subfolder:

- I don't want to have to change my host (and my customers hosts)
- I need to keep drupal in a subfolder on my domaine (`mydomain.tld/drupal`)

Every website should be accessible like this :

- mydomain.tld/drupal/customer1.com
- mydomain.tld/drupal/customer2.org

I know that I have to add some configuration in sites/sites.php and I tryed:

```
$sites = array(

    'mydomain.tld.drupal.customX.com' => 'customerX.com'

);
```

But it looks like the rule is not used and I have a not found error...

Could you help me with that?

Comment: What version of Drupal are you using?

Comment: I'm using Drupal 7

Comment: @MARTINDamien Is this dev platform in your local machine or is it hosted ? If hosted do you have a limit on number of subdomains for your site.

Comment: I currently work on my desktop so, I use localhost, but I wish to avoid manipulations on hosts files because I will move this drupal to a dev server and I will need to send the links to customers (and I'm not sure they will be able to modify it). On production servers I will have no limitations.

Comment: Ok if you dont have limitations you could use customer1.mydomain.tld which will be easier to configure.

Comment: Subdomains are not my best choice (I will have to send links to customers from the dev server and they certainly not be able to modify their hosts - we often made new versions of existing websites and domains are already taken by the current site).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create subfolders like this:

yourdomain.com/drupal/sites/site1.com

yourdomain.com/drupal/sites/site2.net

yourdomain.com/drupal/sites/site3.org

and park domains site1.com , site2.net , site3.org to folder yourdomain.com/drupal/

Comment: For `http://localhost/drupal/customer` I have to add `$sites['localhost.drupal.customer'] = 'customer';` and I have to create `<DRUPAL ROOT>/sites/customer` with a `settings.php` in it with DB connection informations. Is that right ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the "$sites = array" part. I know it says it in the comments, but I just list them in the sites.php file:

$sites['mydomain.net'] = 'mydomain.net';

$sites['otherdomain.net'] = 'otherdomain.net';

$sites['thirddomain.net'] = 'thirddomain.net';

And don't forget the folders like Boris mentioned.

Comment: Both of those methods are identical as far as PHP is concerned

Answer (score 0):

It's really tricky to get this working correctly but the documentation is already on Drupal.org - http://drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site check the Subdirectory multi-site section. I've also posted a more concise version [here](http://www.ixis.co.uk/blog/drupal-7-subfolder-multisite-install) which is more to specific needs.